# Select DISTINCT returning too many records

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct, greatest-n-per-group, distinct-on

I have two tables: Products and Items. I want to select `distinct` items that belong to a product based on the `condition` column, sorted by `price ASC`.

```
+-------------------+
| id | name         |
+-------------------+
| 1 | Mickey Mouse  |
+-------------------+

+-------------------------------------+
| id | product_id | condition | price |
+-------------------------------------+
| 1  | 1           | New       | 90   |
| 2  | 1           | New       | 80   |
| 3  | 1           | Excellent | 60   |
| 4  | 1           | Excellent | 50   |
| 5  | 1           | Used      | 30   |
| 6  | 1           | Used      | 20   |
+-------------------------------------+
```

Desired output:

```
+----------------------------------------+
| id | name          | condition | price |
+----------------------------------------+
| 2  | Mickey Mouse  | New       | 80    |
| 4  | Mickey Mouse  | Excellent | 50    |
| 6  | Mickey Mouse  | Used      | 20    |
+----------------------------------------+
```

Here's the query. It returns six records instead of the desired three:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(items.condition), items.price, products.name
FROM products
INNER JOIN items ON products.id = items.product_id
WHERE products.id = 1
ORDER BY items."price" ASC, products.name;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct PostgreSQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (items.condition) items.id, items.condition, items.price, products.name
FROM products
INNER JOIN items ON products.id = items.product_id
WHERE products.id = 1
ORDER BY items.condition, items.price, products.name;
```

> SELECT DISTINCT ON ( expression [, ...] ) keeps only the first row of
>   each set of rows where the given expressions evaluate to equal.

Details [`here`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html)

Answer (score 3):

There is no `distinct()` function in SQL. Your query is being parsed as

```
SELECT DISTINCT (items.condition), ...
```

which is equivalent to

```
SELECT DISTINCT items.condition, ...
```

`DISTINCT` applies to the whole row - if two or more rows all have the same field values, THEN the "duplicate" row is dropped from the result set.

You probably want something more like

```
SELECT items.condition, MIN(items.price), products.name
FROM ...
...
GROUP BY products.id
```

Comment: There is a `DISTINCT ON (...)` "function" in Postgres.

Comment: That's most likely not what he wants. Postgres offers `DISTINCT ON`. Your query also fails to return `items.id`. A simple aggregate function (`min()`) like you propose fails to return additional columns of the chosen row - as opposed to `DISTINCT ON`.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to select distinct items that belong to a product based on the
>   condition column, sorted by price `ASC`.

You most probably want [**`DISTINCT ON`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT):

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (i.condition)
          i.id AS item_id, p.name, i.condition, i.price
   FROM   products p
   JOIN   items    i ON i.products.id = p.id
   WHERE  p.id = 1
   ORDER  BY i.condition, i.price ASC
   )   sub
ORDER  BY item_id;
```

Since the leading columns of `ORDER BY` have to match the columns used in `DISTINCT ON` , you need a subquery to get the sort order you display.

**Better yet:**

```
SELECT i.item_id, p.name, i.condition, i.price
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (condition)
          id AS item_id, product_id, condition, price
   FROM   items
   WHERE  product_id = 1
   ORDER  BY condition, price
   )   i
JOIN   products p ON p.id = i.product_id
ORDER  BY item_id;
```

Should be a bit faster.

Aside: You shouldn't be using the non-descriptive name `id` as identifier. Use `item_id` and `product_id` instead.

More details, links and a benchmark test in this related answer:
[Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Answer (score 0):

Use a SELECT GROUP BY, extracting only the MIN(price) for every PRODUCT/CONDITION.